# Is Poppler Installed and in path

Tags: python, executable, poppler

I am using the convert_from_path from pdf2image to convert pdf documents to text.
the program is working fine on its own.
But when I run an exe created using pyinstaller, I get the error:-
***pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError:Unable to get pagecount. Is poppler installed and in PATH?***

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the poppler_path variable in your call to convert_from_path with the full path to the bin dir where poppler is installed. Example:

```
pages = convert_from_path(pdf_filename,  poppler_path = r'C:\Users\username\Lib\site-packages\poppler-22.01.0\Library\bin')
```